# Moving ONLY text over from one cell of characters to another

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with multiple columns and over 1,000 rows.  In one of the columns ('City') some of the cells have the zip code inside the cell as well eg 'someplace 12345.' I want to move the numbers over to another new column while keeping the city where it is.  Is there a way to do this using excel functions?  I would go through the rows one by one but there are way to many to do that.  Any help is appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Will the format always be like that ... City <space> Zipcode? Also, are Zipcodes only numeric or alphanumeric? What other data would be there? Better, post some sample data. :-)

Comment: Sorry, should have added more example. All examples look like:         'someplace 1234' OR 'other AB4 3GB' (in that case i need everything after 'other' moved) OR 'otherplace 123-324' OR 'lastplace 123 432'. It will always be city first and then zip after.

Comment: Final bit ... so is it safe to assume that the only data in each cell would be City <space> Zipcode?

Comment: yes, exactly that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1))` and then drag and copy. See screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the zip codes are all in 5 digit format:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,5)*1),RIGHT(A1,5),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu item Data > Text to Columns may be useful to you in this case. It allows you to split a column based on a delimiter.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-text-into-different-cells-HA102809804.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming zip code is separated from place name with whitespace and there are no whitespaces except this one, you need these formulas (your original value in cell `A1`):

Place name:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))
```

Zip code:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

If Zip codes are fixed width (5):

Place name:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5-1)
```

Zip code:

```
=RIGHT(A1,5)
```